# Use dplyr to substitute apply

Tags: r, apply, dplyr

I have table like this (but number of columns can be different, I have a number of pairs ref_* + alt_*):

```
+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| GeneID | ref_a | alt_a | ref_b | alt_b |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   a1   |   0   |   1   |   1   |   3   |
|   a2   |   1   |   1   |   7   |   8   |
|   a3   |   0   |   1   |   1   |   3   |
|   a4   |   0   |   1   |   1   |   3   |
+--------+-------+-------+---------------+
```

and need to filter out rows that have ref_a + alt_a < 10 **and** ref_b + alt_b < 10. It's easy to do it with apply, creating additional columns and filtering, but I'm learning to keep my data tidy, so trying to do it with **dplyr**. 
I would use mutate first to create columns with sums and then filter by these sums. But can't figure out how to use mutate in this case.

**Edited:** 
Number of columns is not fixed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to mutate here. Just do the following:

```
require(tidyverse)
df %>%
  filter(ref_a + alt_a < 10 & ref_b + alt_b < 10)
```

If you want to use mutate first you could go with:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(sum1 = ref_a + alt_a, sum2 = ref_b + alt_b) %>%
  filter(sum1 < 10 & sum2 < 10)
```

Edit: The fact that we don't know the number of variables in advance makes it a bit more complicated. However, I think you could use the following code to perform this task (assuming that the variable names are all formated with "_a", "_b" and so on. I hope there is a shorter way to perform this task :)

```
df$GeneID <- as.character(df$GeneID)

df %>%
  gather(variable, value,  -GeneID) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(variable = unlist(strsplit(variable, "_"))[2]) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(GeneID, variable) %>%
  summarise(sum = sum(value)) %>%
  filter(sum < 10) %>% 
  summarise(keepGeneID = ifelse(n() == (ncol(df) - 1)/2, TRUE, FALSE)) %>%
  filter(keepGeneID == TRUE) %>%
  select(GeneID) -> ids

df %>%
  filter(GeneID %in% ids$GeneID)
```

Edit 2: After some rework I was able to improve the code a bit:

```
df$GeneID <- as.character(df$GeneID)

df %>%
  gather(variable, value,  -GeneID) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(variable = unlist(strsplit(variable, "_"))[2]) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(GeneID, variable) %>%
  summarise(sum = sum(value)) %>%
  group_by(GeneID) %>%
  summarise(max = max(sum)) %>%
  filter(max < 10) -> ids

df %>%
  filter(GeneID %in% ids$GeneID)
```

Comment: Thank you, yes, that would work for fixed number of pairs. What if I want to this for n pairs of ref and alt? @Niko

Comment: Please see my edited solution to use n pairs of values.

Comment: Thank you!! Looks much more complicated now :) Will test it!

Comment: Could you please accept my solution if it works for you?